# VB6 - Method or datamember not found

Tags: compiler-errors, vb6

When i try to run this project in VB 6.0 the error i get is: **Method or datamember not found**

the error came for the methods of text when i define it to text boxes , the available methods for the text boxes are count item lbound ubound .

Please help me how to solve it.

```
    Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(Index As Integer)
Dim db_file As String
Dim statement As String
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim ctl As Control

db_file = App.path
If Right$(db_file, 1) <> "\" Then db_file = db_file & "\"
db_file = db_file & "MyDB.mdb"

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = _
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
"Data Source=" & db_file & ";" & _
"Persist Security Info=False"
conn.Open

statement = "INSERT INTO MyTable " & "(Job_Date, Client, Final_Product, Description) " & _
'" VALUES (" & "'" & Date & "', " & "'" & txtClient.Text & "', " & "'" & txtFinalProduct.Text & "', " & "'" & txtDescription.Text & "'" & ")"
conn.Execute statement, , adCmdText
conn.Close
msgbox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: The listed members of count, item, lbound, and ubound indicates that your controls are arrays. So if that is your intention, use item to access the proper array element with an index.  For instance, `txtClient.Item(indexvalue).Text`. If you don't intend the controls to be in array, then change them so they aren't in array(s).

Comment: What is the exact line that has the error?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
statement = "INSERT INTO MyTable " & "(Job_Date, Client, Final_Product, Description) " & _
'" VALUES (" & "'" & Date & "', " & "'" & txtClient.Text & "', " & "'" & txtFinalProduct.Text & "', " & "'" & txtDescription.Text & "'" & ")"
```

. . . move the comment start `'` before the concatenation operator `&` on previous line like this

```
statement = "INSERT INTO MyTable " & "(Job_Date, Client, Final_Product, Description) " ' & _
    " VALUES (" & "'" & Date & "', " & "'" & txtClient.Text & "', " & "'" & txtFinalProduct.Text & "', " & "'" & txtDescription.Text & "'" & ")"
```

. . . otherwise it still expects a string to concatenate which is not supplied.

Comment: @wqw had the right idea, but just didn't quite fix the problem.  The  '  comment start just before the first  &  is commenting out the rest of the statement..